# Display different labels for different parts of line in kendo line chart ASP.NET MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have implemented a kendo line chart which shows schedule for three iterations I1,E1 and C1. Usually in the given kendo line chart examples details are displayed when mouse hovered. How can I display the details such that the details are always available(irrespective of whether the mouse is hovered or not). Please help me in solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the series or seriesDefaults use the labels:

```
labels: { 
   visible: true                   
}
```

or in MVC:

```
.Labels(labels => labels
            .Template("#= category #: \n #= value#%")
            .Visible(true)
)
```

If you want to control the text in the label, use the template property of the labels object:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels.template

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/eZUNi)**